# how to use instruments while testing?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

is there any good tutorial/link on how to use instruments while debugging, especially for memory leaks?

Thanks

Comment: I dont know about instrumentation :)
is it with reference to the the performance tools like Activity Monitor, CPU Sampler, Leaks?