# iPhone Memory leak tool

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there any good visual tool which can be used to detect memory leaks in iPhone. The Leaks tool that comes with XCode is very complex to understand. Is there any simpler tool ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tool that has to be used is Instruments. (Shortcut for it is in Xcode menu: Run -> Run with Perfomance Tool -> Leaks)

If you find it too complex, you can look at WWDC videos about Instruments to learn about. You can also read a tutorial here: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/ as it was mentioned in this question: [how to use instruments while testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554526/how-to-use-instruments-while-testing)

Comment: It should also be noted that the Clang Static Analyzer (Build -> Build and Analyze) finds many leaks (and other bugs) automatically.

Comment: So is "Leaks" instrument/ Clang the only way ?